# Problems with D&D and CCP for custom TransferHandler

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, copy-paste

I have trouble implementing a custom `TransferHandler` for a `JTree` which uses a custom `TreeModel`.
The problem comes from the specific `TreeModel` I use to manage my data.

As far as I understood, in swing Drag & Drop works like this:

1. User starts dragging, data is taken from model through transfer handler
2. User drops data on container
3. importData is called on transfer handler (data should be added to model here)
4. exportDone is called on transfer handler (data should be removed from model here)

This is a huge problem for me, because my model must NOT contain any data twice. What I need is:

1. remove data from model at old location
2. add data to model at new location

I googled for this and the only thing I found was a little hack, basically abusing the importData method to also remove the data first and ignoring the exportDone method.

This works for Drag & Drop, but it breaks CCP functionality.
The CCP is broken because within the `exportDone` method I can not find out whether the export was a Drag & Drop or if it was a Cut. I need to remove the data from the model if it was a cut but not if it was a drop.

Furthermore, I have yet another problem when it comes to the `importData` method with Copy and Cut. In case of a copy I need to clone my data, but when it is a cut I do not need to clone and I actually would prefer if I didn't do it to keep the old references.
But the only argument you are given in the `importData` method is a `TransferSupport` object.
The `TransferSupport` can not tell you whether the action is a copy or cut action.

Here is the code if it is any help: (its huge already, sorry)

```
package pkg;

import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class TransferActionListener implements ActionListener, PropertyChangeListener {
    private JComponent focusOwner = null;

    /*
     * This class is taken from the oracle tutorial website for Copy-Cut-Paste support.
     * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/listpaste.html
     */

    public static final TransferActionListener INSTANCE = new TransferActionListener();

    private TransferActionListener() {
        KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
        manager.addPropertyChangeListener("permanentFocusOwner", this);
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        Object obj = e.getNewValue();
        if (obj instanceof JComponent) {
            focusOwner = (JComponent)obj;
        } else {
            focusOwner = null;
        }
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (focusOwner == null) {
            return;
        }

        String action = (String) e.getActionCommand();
        Action a = focusOwner.getActionMap().get(action);
        if (a != null) {
            a.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(focusOwner, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, null));
        }
    }
}

package pkg;

import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ObjectTransferable<E> implements Transferable {

    /*
     * This class can be used to transfer any kind of java class.
     * Can only be used within the same JVM.
     */

    private final DataFlavor[] flavors;
    private final E obj;

    public ObjectTransferable(E object) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        obj = object;
        flavors = new DataFlavor[] {
            new DataFlavor(DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType + ";class="+object.getClass().getName())
        };
    }

    public ObjectTransferable(E object, DataFlavor flavor) {
        obj = object;
        flavors = new DataFlavor[] {
            flavor
        };
    }

    public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
        if (!isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
            throw new UnsupportedFlavorException(flavor);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
        return flavors;
    }

    public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
        return flavors[0].equals(flavor);
    }

}

package pkg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Node {

    private final String name;
    private final List<Node> children;
    private MyModel model;
    private Node parent;

    public Node(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        children = new ArrayList<>();
        parent = null;
    }

    protected void setModel(MyModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        for (Node child : getChildren()) {
            child.setModel(model);
        }
    }

    protected MyModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    protected void setParent(Node node) {
        parent = node;
    }

    public Node getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void addChild(Node child) {
        addChild(child, getChildren().size());
    }

    public void addChild(Node child, int index) {
        if (child.getParent() == this) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node '"+child+"' is already a child of '"+this+"'.");
        }
        if (child.getParent() != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node '"+child+"' already has a parent.");
        }
        child.setParent(this);
        child.setModel(getModel());
        children.add(index, child);
        fireInsertEvent(child, index);
    }

    public void removeChild(Node child) {
        if (child.getParent() != this) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node '"+child+"' is not a child of '"+this+"'.");
        }
        int index = children.indexOf(child);
        fireRemoveEvent(child, index);
        child.setParent(null);
        child.setModel(null);
        children.remove(index);
    }

    public List<Node> getChildren() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(children);
    }

    protected void fireInsertEvent(Node node, int index) {
        if (getModel() != null) {
            getModel().fireInsertEvent(node, index);
        }
    }

    protected void fireRemoveEvent(Node node, int index) {
        if (getModel() != null) {
            getModel().fireRemoveEvent(node, index);
        }
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}

package pkg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.event.TreeModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TreeModelListener;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeModel;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class MyModel implements TreeModel {

    private final List<TreeModelListener> listeners;
    private Node root;

    public MyModel(Node rootNode) {
        listeners = new ArrayList<>();
        root = rootNode;
        root.setModel(this);
    }

    public Object getRoot() {
        return root;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the parent node for the given child.
     * Assumes that the child is an object of type Node.
     * @param child
     * @return
     */
    public Object getParent(Object child) {
        Node childNode = (Node) child;
        return childNode.getParent();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the child node at index for the given parent.
     * Assumes that the parent is an object of type Node.
     * @param child
     * @return
     */
    public Object getChild(Object parent, int index) {
        Node parentNode = (Node) parent;
        return parentNode.getChildren().get(index);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of children the parent has.
     * Assumes that the parent is an object of type Node.
     * @param child
     * @return
     */
    public int getChildCount(Object parent) {
        Node parentNode = (Node) parent;
        return parentNode.getChildren().size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the index of child within the given parent.
     * Returns -1 if child is not a child of parent.
     * Assumes that the parent is an object of type Node.
     * @param child
     * @return
     */
    public int getIndexOfChild(Object parent, Object child) {
        Node parentNode = (Node) parent;
        return parentNode.getChildren().indexOf(child);
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the given node does not have any children.
     * Assumes that node is an object of type Node.
     * @param child
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isLeaf(Object node) {
        Node someNode = (Node) node;
        return someNode.getChildren().isEmpty();
    }

    /**
     * Removes all nodes, within the iterable, from this model.
     * If an object from the iterable is not a Node this method will throw an exception.
     * @param nodes
     */
    public void removeNodes(Iterable<Object> nodes) {
        for (Object obj : nodes) {
            Node node = (Node) obj;
            Node parent = node.getParent();

            parent.removeChild(node);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adds all nodes, within the iterable, as children to the given parent.
     * Starts the insertion at startIndex and counts up by one for each insertion.
     * If an object from the iterable is not a Node this method will throw an exception.
     * @param parent
     * @param startIndex
     * @param nodes
     */
    public void insertNodes(Object parent, int startIndex, Iterable<Object> nodes) {
        Node parentNode = (Node) parent;
        if (startIndex > parentNode.getChildren().size()) {
            startIndex = parentNode.getChildren().size();
        }
        for (Object obj : nodes) {
            Node child = (Node) obj;
            parentNode.addChild(child, startIndex++);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Not used and not implement.
     * Will throw an {@link UnsupportedOperationException} if called.
     */
    public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {
        // Never being used.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented.");
    }

    public void addTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
        listeners.add(l);
    }

    public void removeTreeModelListener(TreeModelListener l) {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a TreeModelEvent for the given node and index 
     * and calls treeNodesInserted on all registered listeners.
     * The node must never be null.
     * @param node
     * @param index
     */
    protected void fireInsertEvent(Node node, int index) {
        TreeModelEvent e = makeEvent(node, index);
        for (TreeModelListener l : listeners) {
            l.treeNodesInserted(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Constructs a TreeModelEvent for the given node and index 
     * and calls treeNodesRemoved on all registered listeners.
     * The node must never be null.
     * @param node
     * @param index
     */
    protected void fireRemoveEvent(Node node, int index) {
        TreeModelEvent e = makeEvent(node, index);
        for (TreeModelListener l : listeners) {
            l.treeNodesRemoved(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a TreeModelEvent for the given node and index.
     * The node must never be null.
     * @param node
     * @param index
     * @return
     */
    protected TreeModelEvent makeEvent(Node node, int index) {
        return new TreeModelEvent(this, makePath(node), asArray(index), asArray(node));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a {@link TreePath} for the given node.
     * The last component in the path will be the given node.
     * The root of the tree will not be a part of the path.
     * @param node
     * @return
     */
    protected TreePath makePath(Object node) {
        if (node == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        Deque<Object> pathAsStack = new LinkedList<>();
        Object current = node;
        while (current != null) {
            pathAsStack.add(current);
            current = getParent(current);
        }
        Object[] pathAsArray = new Object[pathAsStack.size() - 1];
        int index = 0;
        while (pathAsStack.size() > 1) {
            pathAsArray[index++] = pathAsStack.pollLast();
        }
        return new TreePath(pathAsArray);
    }

    /**
     * Simple wrapper.
     * @param index
     * @return
     */
    protected int[] asArray(int index) {
        return new int[] {index};
    }

    /**
     * Simple wrapper.
     * @param index
     * @return
     */
    protected Object[] asArray(Object obj) {
        return new Object[] {obj};
    }

}

package pkg;

import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class JTreeTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // This flavor will be used for the transfers.
    private final DataFlavor nodeFlavor;

    public JTreeTransferHandler() {
        // We always transfer a List of objects.
        nodeFlavor = new DataFlavor(List.class, List.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    /*
     * Next three methods will handle the canImport functionality.
     * canImport determines whether an import can take place or is rejected.
     * We will treat this differently for Drag & Drop and Copy-Cut-Paste.
     */

    public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        try {
            // First, check for the right flavor.
            if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(nodeFlavor)) {
                return false;
            }
            // Then, handle the special cases.
            if (support.isDrop()) {
                return canImportDrop(support);
            } else {
                return canImportPaste(support);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* 
             * We do this because otherwise the exception would be swallowed by swing
             * and we wont know what happened.
             */
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private boolean canImportDrop(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        support.setShowDropLocation(true);

        /*
         * Can not drop a path on itself or on a descendant of itself.
         * We know, that the component is a JTree.
         */
        JTree tree = (JTree) support.getComponent();

        JTree.DropLocation dl = (JTree.DropLocation) support.getDropLocation();
        TreePath dropPath = dl.getPath();

        /* 
         * If one of the selected paths is supposed to be dropped on 
         * itself or a descendant of itself, return false.
         */
        TreePath[] selectedPaths = tree.getSelectionPaths();
        for (TreePath selectedPath : selectedPaths) {
            if (selectedPath.isDescendant(dropPath)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Otherwise, return true.
        return true;
    }

    private boolean canImportPaste(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        /*
         * Can only paste nodes if tree has exactly one path selected.
         * Otherwise the paste location is not known...
         */
        JTree tree = (JTree) support.getComponent();
        TreePath[] selectedPaths = tree.getSelectionPaths();
        return selectedPaths.length == 1 && selectedPaths[0] != null;
    }

    /*
     * Next three methods will handle the importData functionality.
     * importData will insert the data into our model.
     * We will treat this differently for Drag & Drop and Copy-Cut-Paste.
     */

    public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        try {
            // Check if we can import.
            if(!canImport(support)) {
                return false;
            }
            // Handle the different situations.
            if (support.isDrop()) {
                return importDataDrop(support);
            } else {
                return importDataPaste(support);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* 
             * We do this because otherwise the exception would be swallowed by swing
             * and we wont know what happened.
             */
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private boolean importDataDrop(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        /* 
         * When dropped the action is a MOVE command.
         * We must first remove the old data, and then insert the new data.
         */
        List<Object> data = extractImportData(support);

        /*
         * We know, that the component is always a JTree and the model is always a MyModel.
         */
        JTree tree = (JTree) support.getComponent();
        MyModel model = (MyModel) tree.getModel();

        // Extract drop location and drop index
        JTree.DropLocation dl = (JTree.DropLocation)support.getDropLocation();

        TreePath destPath = dl.getPath();
        Object parent = destPath.getLastPathComponent();
        int index = dl.getChildIndex();

        if (index == -1) {
            // Drop location is on top of a node
            index = model.getChildCount(parent);
        }

        // First remove data
        model.removeNodes(data);
        // Then insert data
        model.insertNodes(parent, index, data);

        return true;
    }

    private boolean importDataPaste(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        /* 
         * This is either a copy & paste or a cut & paste.
         * If this was a copy & paste we need to clone the data!
         * If this was a cut & paste we can simply insert it.
         * 
         * Unfortunately, there is no good way to know...
         */

        List<Object> data = extractImportData(support);

        // no way to know... what a bummer.
        int action = MOVE;
        if ((action & COPY) == COPY) {
            // When we copy, then clone the list data!
            // somehow clone the data...
        }

        /*
         * We know, that the component is always a JTree and the model is always a MyModel.
         */
        JTree tree = (JTree) support.getComponent();
        MyModel model = (MyModel) tree.getModel();

        // Extract drop location and drop index
        // Drop location depends on selection
        TreePath destPath = tree.getSelectionPath();
        Object parent;
        // Path can be null if nothing is selected.
        if (destPath == null) {
            parent = model.getRoot();
        } else {
            parent = destPath.getLastPathComponent();
        }
        int index = model.getChildCount(parent);

        /* 
         * Inserts the new nodes into the model. 
         * Nodes must NOT be contained in the model at this point!
         */
        model.insertNodes(parent, index, data);

        return true;
    }

    /*
     * This method handles the removal of data if the action was a Cut.
     */

    protected void exportDone(JComponent c, Transferable data, int action) {
        // Only a move action needs to remove the old data.
        if (action != MOVE) {
            return;
        }
        /* 
         * When this is a drag & drop, do nothing.
         * When this was a cut, then remove the old data.
         */

        // no way to know... what a bummer.
        boolean isDragAndDrop = true;
        if (!isDragAndDrop) {
            // Extract nodes from data
            List<Object> nodes = extractImportData(data);

            // The component is always a JTree and always has a TreeModel2 as its model
            JTree tree = (JTree) c;
            MyModel model = (MyModel) tree.getModel();

            // Remove the nodes from the model
            // This will throw an exception if the nodes are not contained in the model!
            model.removeNodes(nodes);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Creates our Transferable as a list of all selected paths in the tree.
     */

    protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c) {
        try {
            // Component is always a JTree
            JTree tree = (JTree) c;

            // Extract nodes to be transfered => Always the selected nodes
            TreePath[] paths = tree.getSelectionPaths();
            if(paths != null) {
                List<Object> nodeList = new ArrayList<>(); 
                for (TreePath path : paths) {
                    nodeList.add(path.getLastPathComponent());
                }
                return new ObjectTransferable<List<Object>>(nodeList, nodeFlavor);
            }
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            /* 
             * We do this because otherwise the exception would be swallowed by swing
             * and we wont know what happened.
             */
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
        return COPY_OR_MOVE;
    }

    /*
     * Utility methods for extracting data from a transfer.
     */

    private List<Object> extractImportData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
        return extractImportData(support.getTransferable());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private List<Object> extractImportData(Transferable trans) {
        try {
            return (List<Object>) trans.getTransferData(nodeFlavor);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // We dont need a checked exception because we wont do anything with it anyways.
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}

package pkg;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.DropMode;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.TransferHandler;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeSelectionModel;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new App();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * The number of nodes that will be randomly constructed. Must be smaller then NODE_NAMES.length.
     */
    private static final int NODE_COUNT = 10;
    /**
     * An array containing random names that will be used for constructing the tree.
     */
    private static final String[] NODE_NAMES = new String[] {
        "Albert",   "Annabell", "Benjamin", "Bella",        "Cedric",       "Cecile",
        "David",    "Danielle", "Emanuel",  "Elisabeth",    "Frederick",    "Felicita",
        "Georg",    "Giselle",  "Hans",     "Henriette",    "Ismael",       "Irene",
        "Joshua",   "Joceline", "Kyle",     "Kaithlin",     "Lyod",         "Lisa",
        "Michael",  "Michelle", "Norbert",  "Nele",         "Olaf",         "Ophelia",
        "Robert",   "Renate",   "Stuart",   "Sabrina",      "Theo",         "Tania",
        "Ulric",    "Ursula",   "Victor",   "Veronica",     "William",      "Wilma"
    };

    /*
     * If the static final variables have illegal values we will throw an exception at class initialization.
     */
    static {
        if (NODE_NAMES.length < NODE_COUNT) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Node count must be no bigger then: "+NODE_NAMES.length);
        }
    }

    public App() {
        // Setup the frame
        JFrame frmTreeModelTest = new JFrame();
        frmTreeModelTest.setTitle("JTree Transfer Handler Test");
        frmTreeModelTest.setSize(600, 480);
        frmTreeModelTest.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frmTreeModelTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Scroll panel for the tree
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        frmTreeModelTest.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        /*
         * Construct our initial nodes.
         * This will create a random tree which contains all kinds of names.
         */
        Node rootNode = new Node("Root");
        List<String> possibleNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(NODE_NAMES));
        List<Node> existingNodes = new ArrayList<>();
        existingNodes.add(rootNode);
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < NODE_COUNT; i++) {
            int nameID = random.nextInt(possibleNames.size());
            Node node = new Node(possibleNames.remove(nameID));

            int parentID = random.nextInt(existingNodes.size());
            Node parent = existingNodes.get(parentID);

            parent.addChild(node);
            existingNodes.add(node);
        }

        // The JTree that will be used for this test
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.setModel(new MyModel(rootNode));   
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.DISCONTIGUOUS_TREE_SELECTION);
        tree.setTransferHandler(new JTreeTransferHandler());
        tree.setDragEnabled(true);
        tree.setDropMode(DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT);

        /*
         * This code was taken from the oracle tutorial website for Copy-Cut-Paste support.
         * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/listpaste.html
         */
        tree.getActionMap().put(TransferHandler.getCutAction().getValue(Action.NAME), TransferHandler.getCutAction());
        tree.getActionMap().put(TransferHandler.getCopyAction().getValue(Action.NAME), TransferHandler.getCopyAction());
        tree.getActionMap().put(TransferHandler.getPasteAction().getValue(Action.NAME), TransferHandler.getPasteAction());

        scrollPane.setViewportView(tree);

        // Construct the menu bar with CCP functionality.
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        frmTreeModelTest.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(mnEdit);

        JMenuItem mntmCopy = new JMenuItem("Copy");
        mntmCopy.addActionListener(TransferActionListener.INSTANCE);
        mntmCopy.setActionCommand((String) TransferHandler.getCopyAction().getValue(Action.NAME));
        mntmCopy.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        mnEdit.add(mntmCopy);

        JMenuItem mntmCut = new JMenuItem("Cut");
        mntmCut.addActionListener(TransferActionListener.INSTANCE);
        mntmCut.setActionCommand((String) TransferHandler.getCutAction().getValue(Action.NAME));
        mntmCut.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        mnEdit.add(mntmCut);

        JMenuItem mntmPaste = new JMenuItem("Paste");
        mntmPaste.addActionListener(TransferActionListener.INSTANCE);
        mntmPaste.setActionCommand((String) TransferHandler.getPasteAction().getValue(Action.NAME));
        mntmPaste.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
        mnEdit.add(mntmPaste);

        // Show the frame
        frmTreeModelTest.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The drag & drop works, but Copy-Cut-Paste does not quite work because of the missing information...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  Note, an MCVE of this problem would need imports and a `main(String[])` to put it on screen (in addition to the current code, which all seems necessary) so it might not be very 'minimal' (the code is already almost 250 LOC) but it should at least be 'complete'.  BTW - CCP means 'Cut, Copy & Paste'?

Comment: Okay, it took me an hour to create, but I made the MCVE and added it to the original post. And yes, CCP means Copy-Cut-Paste, I thought that was the normal abbreviation.

Answer (score 1):

Before this I assume you know that exportDone is called after importData for drag and drop and called before importData for ccp(cut copy) 
Also I assume you know that drag will call cut action and ctrl+drag will call copy action..
So, in order to know that whether the operation is dnd or ccp you have to set a flag at importData
Here I have used isDrag flag to set that..

```
public class JTreeTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

private final DataFlavor nodeFlavor;

Boolean isCut;
Boolean isdrag = false;

@Override
public int getSourceActions(JComponent c) {
    return COPY_OR_MOVE;
}

@Override
protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent source) {

}

@Override
protected void exportDone(JComponent source, Transferable data, int action) {
    isCut = action == MOVE; //to check whether the operation is cut or copy
    if (isdrag) {
        if (isCut) {
            //Implement you drag code (normal drag)
        } else {
            //Implement you ctrl+drag code
        }
    }
    isdrag = false; //resetting the dnd flag
}

@Override
public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
    if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavors.nodeFlavor)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (support.isDrop()) {
        return canImportDnd();
    } else {
        return canImportccp();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
    if (!canImport(support)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (support.isDrop()) {
        isdrag = true;//To know whether it is a drag and drop in exportdone
        if (support.getDropAction() == MOVE) {
            //Implement you drag code (normal drag)
        } else if (support.getDropAction() == COPY) {
            //Implement you ctrl+drag code
        }
    } else if (isCut) {
        //Implement you cut ctrl+x code
    }

    return true;
}

}
```